# Do the environment variables set via IntelliJ IDEA correspond to operating system's ones?

Tags: windows, intellij-idea, environment-variables

What is the relationship between the environment variables set via IntelliJ IDEA (in run config menu) vs. the OS's ones?

Somehow the variable I just created in IDEA run configuration is not appearing in Windows Control Panel | System | Env Variables.

Does it have something to do with their scoping or is it something different?

Would appreciate if someone can shed a bit more light on it for me.  Thank you.